# Ember computed property _super

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to know if there is a way to get the `_super` for a computed property?

For example:

`controllers/core-controller.js`

```
export default Controller.extend({
    myAttribute: computed(function() {
        return {
            bar: this.get('bar')
        };
    });
});
```

`controllers/my-controller.js`

```
import CoreController from 'controllers/core-controller';

export default CoreController.extend({
    myAttribute: computed(function() {
        let super = this.get('_super') //I'm trying to get the myAttribute object from the CoreController
        return merge(super, { foo: 'foo' });
    });
});
```

What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by calling `this._super(...arguments)`:

```
import CoreController from 'controllers/core-controller';

export default CoreController.extend({
    myAttribute: computed(function() {
        let superValue = this._super(...arguments);
        return merge(superValue, { foo: 'foo' });
    });
});
```

Also demoed in this twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/dba33b9fca4c9635edb0

Comment: I tried it first before I asked this question and it wasn't working. Somehow now it works fine, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You could define the property during initialization:

```
export default CoreController.extend({
  defineMyAttribute: Ember.on('init', function() {
    const superValue = this.get('myAttribute');

    Ember.defineProperty(this, 'myProperty', Ember.computed(function() {
      return merge(superValue, { foo: 'foo' });
    }));
  })
})
```

Caveat: you'd only get `superValue` once, during init. If `myAttribute` had dependencies, it could recompute, but it would always get the *original* value from the super class to merge in, never an updated one.